# C++ sleep for undetermined amount of time

Tags: c++, sleep

In my code I want my system to sleep, until a condition has been met. An after having searched i have found `#include <unistd.h>`, but to me it just looks like it sleeps until the time frame has been met. I was wondering if there was a easy way to make the program wait until the condition has been reached.

Here you have a sample of the code to clarify my point

```
bool check() {
   while (condition) {
       sleep.here();
   } else {
       run.the.rest();
   }
}
```

Comment: They make [condition variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/condition_variable) for this very thing.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this, but they depend on what sort of condition you're waiting for. The condition variable is for waiting for another thread to wake you, select/*poll can be used to wait for something to arrive on a socket, etc.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Superlokkus If you use any of `[mcve]`, `[mre]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]`  or `[example]` in comment, it will get nicely formatted like this: [mcve]. But I wouldn't say reproducible example is needed here. OP posted their needs and pseudo-code to illustrate it.

Comment: "OP posted their needs and pseudo-code to illustrate it." Very vague and contradictory needs and pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your incomplete pseudo-code and description, here is a class `contidion_t`, where you can set your condition via `set_condition`, and a thread blocking in `loop` will wake up, every time you set it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

struct condition_t {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void loop(T the_rest)  {
        while(running) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock_guard(m);
            cv.wait(lock_guard, [this] { return ready.load(); });
            the_rest();
            ready = false;
        }
    }

    void set_condition(bool value) {
        ready = value;
        if (value) {
            cv.notify_one();
        }
    }

    void stop_running() {
        running = false;
        ready = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
    ~condition_t () {stop_running();}

private:
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic<bool> ready{false};
    std::atomic<bool> running{true};
};

int main() {
    condition_t condition;
    std::thread thread(&condition_t::loop<void (void)>, &condition, [] () {
        std::cout << "Doing the rest" << std::endl;
    });
    std::cout << "Thread created but waits\nInput something for continue:";
    int something;
    std::cin >> something;
    std::cout << "Continueing\n";
    condition.set_condition(true);
    std::cout << "Input something to stop running:";
    std::cin >> something;
    condition.stop_running();

    thread.join();
}
```